# TypeError: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple. in Django - `python manage.py harvest`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, pytest-bdd

I'm trying to integrate Aloe for BDD testing in a Django 5.0 project, but I'm encountering a TypeError related to requires_system_checks. This issue arises when I attempt to run Aloe tests using the command python manage.py harvest. Here are the details:

Environment:
Django Version: 4.2.8
Aloe Version: 0.2.0
Python Version: 3.9
Django Settings:
In my settings.py, I have the following setup for testing:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'aloe_django',
    'django_nose',
    'rest_framework',
    'ad_manager',
]

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

When I run `python manage.py harvest`, I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in __init__
    raise TypeError("requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.")
TypeError: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.
```

**Attempts to Resolve:
**

- I've confirmed that Aloe is correctly installed and appears in the installed apps.
- I've also tried running the tests without specifying a custom test runner, but the issue persists.
  **Questions:
  **
- What could be causing this TypeError in Django 4 when running Aloe tests?
- Is there a specific configuration or setup required for Aloe to work with Django 4?
- Has anyone else encountered this issue with Aloe and Django, and how was it resolved?

Any help or guidance on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so far I just switched to behave but not a true solution.